# Arrange crosswise, then arrange vertically

Tags: multicol, exam

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
  $1+1=$(\makebox[3em]{}).
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate} [A.]
      \item 0
      \item 1
      \item 2
      \item 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How can output [image]

Comment: You need the `tasks` package, not `multicol` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

  $1+1=$(\makebox[3em]{}).
  \begin{tasks}[counter-format = tsk[A]. ](2)
      \task 0
      \task 1
      \task 2
      \task 3
  \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]